# Why <script> not working inside the <head> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and JavaScript. I have put  tag in head, but it is not working. Its code is given. However, it works when I place it in the body section. Why it is not working inside the  tag?

```html
<head>
  <script>
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello, World!";
  <script>
</head>

<body>
   <p id = "demo"> </p>
</body>
```

Comment: because id demo not find on head section on page load

Comment: Read This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Comment: If you add script to head it's executed before the body is rendered.Move your script to the bottom of body or add something like JQuery document.ready event callback there.

Comment: also, your `<script>` tag isn't closed. you have two open `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, but your script is executed before your DOM is loaded properly. Use

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello, World!";
}
```

Also it's possible to use the `onload` attribute:

```
<body onload="jsFunction()"></body>
```